Can a Fortran function reference interfere with assignment?
I know that (at least at one point), the following is invalid Fortran due to aliasing
program main

integer :: x, y

! compilers assume a and b to be distinct
y = f(x, x)

contains

integer function f(a, b) result(c)
  integer, intent(in out) :: a, b
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = a ! compiler can optimize to c = 1
end function

end program main

But is the following valid?
program main

integer :: x(3)

x = [1, 2, 3]
x = square_me(x)

contains

function square_me(a) result(squared)
  integer, intent(in out) :: a(3)
  integer                 :: squared(3)

  squared = a ** 2
  a(1) = 0 ! nasty side-effect
end function

end program main

It works in gfortran, but I'm not sure if it's standard-conforming.
I'm aware side-effects in functions are not a good idea. I'm dealing with >100k lines of legacy code that likes to use C-style integer-code-returning functions and modifying arguments, so this question is specifically about the standard.

Which aspect worries you? (I can guess, but there's no harm in being explicit.)

Whatever the concern I would strongly advise against functions with side effects, it's just asking for trouble. Use subroutines in such cases. Keep your functions pure.

@IanBush The comment "nasty side-effect" was meant to convey that idea :)

@francescalus I was concerned that the compiler would try to share references to x being returned and the result variable squared. In other words, I know the right hand side is evaluated first, but when arrays are involved I am less sure what the standard says (in particular I've observed a lot of static-allocation in this program).

Doesn't matter if it was meant to convey an idea.  @IanBush's advice should be heeded.  As to your first example, it's invalid Fortran.  A compiler can do whatever it wants including setting c = 1.  Your second example does not involve aliasing.

@steve -1. There are plenty of good reasons to ask questions where you know something is bad, but still need an answer. "Just don't do that" is not helpful to anyone trying to interpret, edit, and improve decades old code.

Sure.  It is also important to formulate a question correctly.  The second code example has absolutely nothing to do with aliasing.

@Adam I can see why you are asking, and even if the language isn't perfect it seems a reasonable question to me, after all part of the reason for asking is to learn. But the point behind my previous comment is to convey to somebody new looking at this that though, with care, this sort of thing might be allowed it is a seriously bad idea.

If I weren't still on a voting strike I would absolutely vote this and similar questions up. The intent behind the question is clear, and any misconception evidenced by (mis-)use of terminology is entirely on topic for questions and answers on this site.

@francescalus, The intent is clear?  Question in the title concerns aliasing.  The title is misleading.  The actual subject is about functions with side-effects.

@steve, you and I know the answer and you and I wouldn't ask the question. The answer to the exact question asked in the title may well be "no" but that arguably would be a terrible answer. Side effects and aliasing are so very closely linked that if we reject any question which confuses the two, we neglect almost every opportunity to elaborate. To precisely ask a question about this instance is to beg the question.

@francescalus, I'm not suggesting that the question be rejected.  I'm suggesting that the title should be fixed to reflect reality.  If someone is searching for answers about side effects, I doubt that she'll use 'aliasing' as a search term.

@steve, better?

@steve I realize now that the title is pretty dumb with the info I've learned here, but to give it a little perspective: Fortran is (relatively) unique in that arguments are passed by reference, and since Fortran "returns" results by assigning to a result variable (function name or otherwise), I thought it was possible that results were also "returned by reference" - I'm not good enough at the standard to find out myself, so I thought the second example might be invalid for aliasing.

@francescalus, much better.  Although I'll note that the RHS is completely evaluated prior to assignment to the LHS, so a side effect cannot cause an issue in the code y = f(x,x).  Fortran 2023, 10.1.4 likely is more important for an expression on the RHS, i.e., y = f(x,x) + x.  Here, the side effect might corrupt that trailing addendum (see Note 1).  Note, Fortran allows the evaluation to be re-ordered such one could have y = x + f(x,x) where x initializes an accumulator and then f(,x,x) is evaulated and added to accumulator.

Neither main program is valid.
The so-called aliasing rules in Fortran are generally taken to mean those restrictions which apply to entities during the execution of a procedure. In an assignment statement, however, evaluation of the right-hand side is fully performed before the left-hand side is affected.
Instead, what breaks the second main program is a restriction on side effects of functions.
A side effect is restricted (F2018, 10.1.4) in that, except in some cases not applicable here:

if a function reference causes definition or undefinition of an actual argument of the function, that argument or any associated entities shall not appear elsewhere in the same statement

The assignment to a(1) causes definition of the actual argument x, so x may not appear elsewhere in the assignment statement (including the left-hand side).
There are several other (perhaps surprising) restrictions on side effects in functions. Let's just say: avoid side effects in functions if you can unless you really know the rules, and can be sure that everyone using your function also really really knows the rules.

So functions are able to (but of course shouldn't) perform side-effects on their arguments as long as those arguments don't appear multiple times in a statement? (either the target of assignment or something like z = foo(x) + foo(x)) AKA without the assignment to a, it is valid?

There are effects which last beyond the statement in which the side effect happens. These are too subtle for a comment, and beyond the scope of this question, but fall under the "even if you know the rules, don't assume other people do" rule. Truly, side effects in functions aren't nice.

I'd maybe even go so far to say that a SO question asking "what are the restrictions on side effects in Fortran functions?" would be closed as too broad.
